# c - What is the most efficient way of converting char * array to int and float?

Tags: c

Sorry if it was already asked before, but I really couldn't find a clear answer to this question.
Please, tell me, what is the fastest way of converting:

```
char * array to int
char * array to float
```

char * array stores a number, for example:

```
"12345"
"1234,56789"
```

If the fastest ways for x86 and x64 systems are different, please tell both of them.

EDIT: By "fastest", I mean "the most efficient", not "the most simple to use".

Comment: Try looking at atoi() and atof(). I just wonder how google has missed that one????

Comment: I know a couple of ways, but I need the fastest way - will be useful for processing a big chunks of data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Start with atoi() and atof(), measure the speed, decide if it's a problem - then look for a solution

edit - it's *almost* certain that the I/O will dominate any time spent doing the conversion. If the conversion time does matter (after you profile) then if you know the format ie. ints are always 4digits, floats always have 5 decimal places, you might be able to write a hand tuned routine that does better than the standard lib

Answer (score 2):

You can just use

```
atoi()
```

for ints and

```
atof()
```

for floats.

Answer (score 1):

For `int`, the obvious loop is probably the fastest.

For `float`, it's much more complicated. If you don't care if the result is right, a similarly trivial loop is also fine. If you need the exact result, you'll want to use `strtod` or `atof` or similar since rolling your own is extremely difficult.